# Ruby on Rails: Undefined Method Error with has_one associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

For some reason I'm getting an NoMethodError for some query, which actually works in the rails console.

Code in index.html.erb

```
@requests.first.acceptance
```

This is my Error

```
undefined method `acceptance' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Arrangement:0x000000042ceeb8>
```

These are my Modules.

```
class Arrangement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :acceptance
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :offer, inverse_of: :arrangements
end

class Acceptance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :acceptances
  has_one :arrangement
end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :requests
  has_one :arrangement
end
```

This is my Controller

```
def index 
    @requests = Array.new
    for request in current_user.requests do 
        @requests << Arrangement.where("request_id = ?", request.id)
    end
    @acceptances = Array.new
    for acceptance in current_user.acceptances do 
         @acceptances << Arrangement.where("acceptance_id = ?", acceptance.id)
    end
end
```

I can't figure out what I've done wrong here. Everything works in the console, though not in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Arrangement.where("request_id = ?", request.id)
```

Returns an array-like relation object which may contain multiple records, not just a single record.

However, on this line in your controller

```
@requests << Arrangement.where("request_id = ?", request.id)
```

You're adding the relation to your array, so that

```
@requests.first.acceptance
```

Returns the relation, instead of the first record.

One way to fix this is to do this in your controller:

```
@requests = Array.new
for request in current_user.requests do 
    @requests << Arrangement.where("request_id = ?", request.id).first
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) Even though I found the error by myself now, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: You're welcome! Tiny little bugs like these are often the hardest to find. ;) And most of them wait to turn up until it's Friday!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I was passing an array in the @requests array in my controller.